# python plotly animation graph

Tags: python, plotly

I am working with python, I have a time series dataset. My data contains 16 columns for distances as distance_0 for segment 0 and distance_1 for segment 1..., time. I want to plot segment (x) and distance (y) with time animation like in the image (it is one timestamp graph)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DI7YV.png)

Is there a way to plot a graph with time animation, I tried plotly.express:

## Défénir le module pour le dessin des graphiques

def plot_1(data,title_typ):

```
a=px.scatter(data1, x="0", y="Dist_0", animation_frame="Time",size="Ampl_0", range_x=[-1,16], range_y=[-1,40])
b=px.scatter(data1, x="1", y="Dist_1", animation_frame="Time",size="Ampl_1", range_x=[-1,16], range_y=[-1,40])
c=px.scatter(data1, x="2", y="Dist_2", animation_frame="Time",size="Ampl_2", range_x=[-1,16], range_y=[-1,40])
d=px.scatter(data1, x="3", y="Dist_3", animation_frame="Time",size="Ampl_3", range_x=[-1,16], range_y=[-1,40])
e=px.scatter(data1, x="4", y="Dist_4", animation_frame="Time",size="Ampl_4", range_x=[-1,16], range_y=[-1,40])
f=px.scatter(data1, x="5", y="Dist_5", animation_frame="Time",size="Ampl_5", range_x=[-1,16], range_y=[-1,40])
g=px.scatter(data1, x="6", y="Dist_6", animation_frame="Time",size="Ampl_6", range_x=[-1,16], range_y=[-1,40])
h=px.scatter(data1, x="7", y="Dist_7", animation_frame="Time",size="Ampl_7", range_x=[-1,16], range_y=[-1,40])
i=px.scatter(data1, x="8", y="Dist_8", animation_frame="Time",size="Ampl_8", range_x=[-1,16], range_y=[-1,40])
j=px.scatter(data1, x="9", y="Dist_9", animation_frame="Time",size="Ampl_9", range_x=[-1,16], range_y=[-1,40])
k=px.scatter(data1, x="10", y="Dist_10", animation_frame="Time",size="Ampl_10", range_x=[-1,16], range_y=[-1,40])
l=px.scatter(data1, x="11", y="Dist_11", animation_frame="Time",size="Ampl_11", range_x=[-1,16], range_y=[-1,40])
m=px.scatter(data1, x="12", y="Dist_12", animation_frame="Time",size="Ampl_12", range_x=[-1,16], range_y=[-1,40])
n=px.scatter(data1, x="13", y="Dist_13", animation_frame="Time",size="Ampl_13", range_x=[-1,16], range_y=[-1,40])
o=px.scatter(data1, x="14", y="Dist_14", animation_frame="Time",size="Ampl_14", range_x=[-1,16], range_y=[-1,40])
p=px.scatter(data1, x="15", y="Dist_15", animation_frame="Time",size="Ampl_15", range_x=[-1,16], range_y=[-1,40])


data=[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p]

layout= dict(title=title_typ, xaxis=dict(title='Segment'),yaxis=dict(title='Distance (mètres)'))
fig= dict(data=data, layout=layout)
iplot(fig, filename=title_typ)
```

it gave me this error: ValueError: 
    Invalid element(s) received for the 'size' property of scatter.marker
        Invalid elements include: [nan]

```
The 'size' property is a number and may be specified as:
  - An int or float in the interval [0, inf]
  - A tuple, list, or one-dimensional numpy array of the above
```

I tried with go_scatter but i don't know how to add animation.

Thank you

Comment: Do you want to show the trace of the line and the point moving on it or what?

Comment: The line in the image show one timestamp or one row. I want to show the same line in the image (I did it in excel) with time animation, so it will start with same line in the image and after that the line for the second row...